# What is the number next to the bonus?

Tags: inflation-rpg

Under the actual level of an area, there is occasionally a bonus.  Next to the bonus is a number in parentheses.  What does this number mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the number of fights the bonus will last.  It will decrease every fight, even if you're not in that area, so if you want that bonus, make sure you're fighting there.